# how to install Vodafone k3800

Tags: 12.04, drivers

I'm new Linux user.
I  have Vodafone modem (model k3800) but don't know how to install it on my PC. 
I've tried cmd

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

and also

```
sudo apt-get install install.sh
```

It shows message:

> ```
> could not find any package by regex "install.sh"
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iam using k3800 on my ubuntu 14.04.

these is the way i installed :-

insert your vodafone k3800 dongle and copy file named **PCL_INDIAVDF.tar.gz**  *LOCATED IN LINUX FOLDER* to your **home** folder.

extract **PCL_INDIAVDF.tar.gz**

after extraction type :-

```
  sudo ./install.sh
```

no open dash and search "**Vodafone**"